# Keep text typed in text field after force closing app SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I have a few text fields Where I’d like to keep the contents in them when the app is force closed.so when the app is reloaded and the user goes back to that view, the text will still be there.

My message view may be more difficult as I wouldn’t want text entered in one message thread to be carried over to the next… (if that’s even a possible problem.

Comment: Well if you don't persist the data it won't appear automatically

Comment: Lots of different persistence options are available, including UserDefaults, CoreData, etc. To start, I'd probably look at `@AppStorage`, which itself uses `UserDefaults`.

Comment: ok so I need to persist the data, I will look into that. thank you